# Need to use Replace in string with pentaho with REGEx

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to use "Replace in String" step in Pentaho version 8 with the use of Regular expression. Which means my search string will contain a REGEX and "Replace With" in the step should contain "$10$3" which means it should replace with $1 value of regex append 0 in between and then $3 value of it.

ex: Input :- Ron-234-GR
    Output :- Ron-2340-GR

[Code for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Sf8.png)

Comment: What is the question you would like to be answered and what is the result you're currently getting?

Comment: Basically i want to concatenate an integer in between of my output from the regex. please see the screenshot attached above in my question.

Comment: If you leave out the quotes from your replacement string, it should work. So $10$3

Comment: Yes i think my regex has a problem as it is not working for input string. Something like ex:- HST-RHPLM--.

Comment: If you add a few more examples to your question, maybe it's possible to figure out the desired regex